# How to detect certain words from a given string in Python?

Tags: python

I'm making a basic program to detect certain words from a string and mark the message as SPAM if the string contains the spam keywords but ran into a problem. The compiler doesn't detect it as spam unless I input the exact same strings.

Here's the code :

```python
text = input("text : ")

if(text == 'make a lot of money' in text) or (text == 'buy now'in text) or (text == 'subscribe this 'in text) or (text =='click link' in text):
    print("SPAM")
else:
    print("OKAY")
```

Comment: `(text == 'buy now' in text)` is incorrect. Use `('buy now' in text)`. Same goes for the other 3 conditions

Comment: @Aziz I think it should be  like      'buy now' in text

Comment: @GautamJangid Yes, it was a typo. Fixed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That' because you're comparing with `equals`:

```
text == 'make a lot of money' in text
```

instead just use the `in` command:

```
'make a lot of money' in text
```

will yield `True` if the text contains that string

Answer (score 0):

You're not using correct syntax for if statement, please use this:

```
text = input("text : ")

if 'make a lot of money' in text or 'buy now' in text or 'subscribe this' in text or 'click link' in text:
    print("SPAM")
else:
    print("OKAY")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = input("text : ")

if('make a lot of money' in text) or ('buy now'in text) or ('subscribe this' in text) or ('click link' in text):
    print("SPAM")
else:
    print("OKAY")
```

OR

```
text = input("text : ")
spam_phrases = ['make a lot of money','buy now','subscribe this','click link']

for phrase in spam_phrases:
    if phrase in text:
        print("SPAM")
        break
else:
    print("OKAY")
```