# What is the logic of == and in comparison?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean, logic

So I was looking for questions and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71351526/how-to-detect-certain-words-from-a-given-string-in-python) recent question

The answer for it is very simple but the one thing I noticed is that it actually did return `SPAM` for exact match

So this snippet of code

```
text = 'buy now'

print(text == 'buy now' in text)  # True
```

returns `True` and I don't get why

I tried to figure out by placing brackets in different places and

```
text = 'buy now'

print(text == ('buy now' in text))  # False
```

returns `False` and

```
text = 'buy now'

print((text == 'buy now') in text) # TypeError
```

raises `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bool`

My question is what is happening right here and why is it like that?

**P.S.**

I am running Python 3.8.10 on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: in is a keyword used to either iterating objects or items in a list, or in conditional functions. print(text == 'buy now' in text) This returns True bc 'buy now' is indeed in text. Its kinda like an if.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `==` and `in` are considered comparison operators, so the expression `text == 'buy now' in text` is subject to comparison chaining, making it equivalent to

```
text == 'buy now' and 'buy now' in text
```

Both are operands of `and` are `True`, hence the `True` result.

When you add parentheses, you are either checking if `text == True` (which is `False`) or if `True in text` (which is a `TypeError`; `str.__contains__` doesn't accept a Boolean argument).

Comment: Wow, that seems really strange in that context. I knew chains work with `==, !=, >, <, >=, <=`. Didn't know that it works with `in` also) Thanks for answer

Comment: Yeah, I can see the argument for `in` (and `is`, and their negative companions) to be comparison operators, but I've never really thought it useful to include them in chaining.